# Python py2exe with tkinter (pyw file)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, exe, py2exe

I have made a small program in Python that involves tkinter, and I made it a pyw file because it has a shortcut on the desktop and I do not want the command prompt to get in the way. I used py2exe following the sentdex tutorial on youtube, and I got an output file, but the output file shows an error and exits before I can read it. The pyw file on its own works fine, but I don't know how to get the exe output file to work correctly.

Information:

Python - 3.4.2;

OS - Windows 8.1;

Folder - Multiple items (photos and audio for the program);

Program - A simple animation in tkinter

If you need the program, tell me and I can upload the folder containing the program.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there is not a version of py2exe for python3.x

You'd be best of going for cx_freeze (Sentdex also has a tutorial on that on that)